# Property 'save' does not exist on type 'CardType'

Tags: javascript, typescript

In a function I have, I'm doing some stuff with the properties of an object of type `CardType`. Then, I want to be able to save those changes into my MongoDB database using the `document.save()` function. However, I have my code like this:

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose';
import Card from '../models/Card';

static async updatePriceForCardByID(cardID: Types.ObjectId) {
    const card = await Card.findById(cardID).exec();
    return updatePriceForCard(card!);
}

static async updatePriceForCard(card: CardType) {
   // This function needs some properties of 'card', it only updates the price of the card
   const newPrice = await StarCityController.getUpdatedPriceForCard(card.name, card.number);

   card.prices.push(newPrice);
   card.save(); // <-- Error appears here

   return Card.findById(card._id).populate({ path: 'prices' }).exec();
}
```

and my `CardType` type like this:

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose';

export type CardType = {
    _id: Types.ObjectId,
    name: string,
    prices: [Types.ObjectId],
    number: string,
    sku: string
}
```

the `card.save()` function is not working anymore like it was when my code was in JS. Now, I know that I'm passing a `CardType` as my parameter on my `updatePriceForCard` function, and as such, instead of a mongoose Document, I'm passing a variable of a type that doesn't have a `save` property in it.

My question is, what would be the best approach to tackle something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add the mongoose `Document` type to your `CardType`.

```
import { Types, Document } from 'mongoose';

export type CardType = {
    _id: Types.ObjectId,
    name: string,
    prices: [Types.ObjectId],
    number: string,
    sku: string
} & Document
```

This will add all the necessary document methods to the type. **Make sure to import the `Document` type from mongoose**, otherwise it may use the DOM-`Document` type which will not work.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgFQJ5gKYGcA0cAiEAxgK4gYB28AvnAGZQQhwDkIEFA5hBFhiwG4AUEIwAPSLDgx0GOAGEAhlAAmaTHAC8iIXD1wA%20sBUAuFLKwA6APIAjAFYYiMAJIqcu-RUXkzWGFDAXB76cGCBRNhmANrq2DYOTq4qALohXmS2GFB%20AUGc6XpYANYkuYFcQrQAZATEZJQwIopYqBRE9CTtMMAccCRgKoowGAAKERgAYtBKqgAURMqmCktxAJQ6eouqluHAkVZgJFgAFnNrwltLlliKAG4Y51VAA)